# What does the 1 in match.group(1) mean?

Tags: python

I met the codes here:

```
>>> import urllib, re
>>> prefix = "http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing="
>>> findnothing = re.compile(r"nothing is (\d+)").search
>>> nothing = '12345'
>>> while True:
...     text = urllib.urlopen(prefix + nothing).read()
...     print text
...     match = findnothing(text)
...     if match:
...         nothing = match.group(1)
...         print "   going to", nothing
...     else:
...         break
```

What does the `1` in `match.group(1)` mean?

Comment: Python has reference documentation you know: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/re.html#re.match.group

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `1` in `match.group(1)` represents the first parenthesised subgroup. In your case the first of one.

This is well described in [the official documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/) for [**`re.MatchObject.group()`**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) and best illustrated with an example:

```
>>> m = re.match(r"(\w+) (\w+)", "Isaac Newton, physicist")
>>> m.group(0)       # The entire match
'Isaac Newton'
>>> m.group(1)       # The first parenthesized subgroup.
'Isaac'
>>> m.group(2)       # The second parenthesized subgroup.
'Newton'
>>> m.group(1, 2)    # Multiple arguments give us a tuple.
('Isaac', 'Newton')
```

Answer (score 4):

The 1 is the number of the group -- denoted by the parentheses pair -- in the the expresssion. Your expression has only one group, but imagine matching `"123 456"` with `r"(\d+) (\d+)"`: `group(1)` would be `"123"`, `group(2)` would be `"456"` and `group(0)` is always the whole match, hence `"123 456"`.